# Python suds: Getitng SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, suds

I'm trying to request some data from a website using suds in Python. I'm getting `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>` while creating suds client. I do not get this error when I'm running the project locally but this issue happens when I try to deploy this project to a Linux host so that it can be automated.

One thing to note is, this python code lies behind AppProxy so that it can connect to internet. I have verified using a CURL request that the remote hosts is able to connect to the website.

I'm new to SSL Certificate thing not so sure about this certificate issue, do I need to install any server certificates on the hosts so that it can verified by SSL Validation? Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: are you using `http` or `https` in your code?

Comment: @Aven Desta: https

Comment: did you try http? does it work? `http` in your code

Comment: The AppProxies are setup for https, so I would need it to work with https.